# How to sanitize the value of string argument inside web api filter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, filter

I have web api  application and I want to sanitize data that comes from front-end applications using web api filters.

I have created the following filter:

```
public class StringFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        foreach (var actionArgument in actionContext.ActionArguments)
        {
            if (actionArgument.Value.GetType() == typeof(string))
            {
                var sanitizedString = actionArgument.Value.ToString().Trim();
                sanitizedString = Regex.Replace(sanitizedString, @"\s+", " ");
                actionContext.ActionArguments[actionArgument.Key] = sanitizedString;
            }
            else
            {
                var properties = actionArgument.Value.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                    .Where(x => x.CanRead && x.PropertyType == typeof(string) && x.GetGetMethod(true).IsPublic && x.GetSetMethod(true).IsPublic);
                foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
                {
                    var sanitizedString = propertyInfo.GetValue(actionArgument.Value).ToString().Trim();
                    sanitizedString = Regex.Replace(sanitizedString, @"\s+", " ");
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(actionArgument.Value, sanitizedString);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The problem with this code is the code inside if statement where I want to sanitize the arguments passed as single string I got this error:

> "ClassName": "System.InvalidOperationException",
>           "Message": "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

But if my web api action takes a parameter as dto object which has string properties the code(which is inside the else statement) is working perfectly and strings are sanitized before starting executing the action.

So my question how to sanitize the passed argument in case it was string parameter?

Comment: You are trying to modify the same collection while enumerating it, which is not allowed. Call `.ToList()`  so that you are enumerating a separate collection while modifying the original. ie `foreach (var actionArgument in actionContext.ActionArguments.ToList()) {...`

Comment: @Nkosi you are right .Thank you so much it works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to modify the same collection while enumerating it, which is not allowed. Call `.ToList()`  so that you are enumerating a separate collection while modifying the original. ie `foreach (var actionArgument in actionContext.ActionArguments.ToList()) {...`

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext) {
    foreach (var actionArgument in actionContext.ActionArguments.ToList()) {
        if (actionArgument.Value != null && actionArgument.Value is string) {
            var sanitizedString = actionArgument.Value.ToString().Trim();
            sanitizedString = Regex.Replace(sanitizedString, @"\s+", " ");
            actionContext.ActionArguments[actionArgument.Key] = sanitizedString;
        } else {
            var properties = actionArgument.Value.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                .Where(x => x.CanRead && x.PropertyType == typeof(string) && x.GetGetMethod(true).IsPublic && x.GetSetMethod(true).IsPublic);
            foreach (var propertyInfo in properties) {
                var sanitizedString = propertyInfo.GetValue(actionArgument.Value).ToString().Trim();
                sanitizedString = Regex.Replace(sanitizedString, @"\s+", " ");
                propertyInfo.SetValue(actionArgument.Value, sanitizedString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But I think this should be **actionContext.ActionArguments[actionArgument.Key] = sanitizedString;**

Comment: @Nkosi  How to sanitize List of object in model. Above code is not sanitizing the List.